# How to add text to Inno Setup bevel line above buttons?

Tags: inno-setup

How to add text to Inno Setup bevel line above buttons?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

From the Inno Setup help:

> The special-purpose BeveledLabel message can be used to specify a line
> of text that is shown in the lower left corner of the wizard window
> and uninstaller window. The following is an example:

```
[Messages]
BeveledLabel=Inno Setup
```

Comment: Thank you for this information and example.
I wish you a nice day,
Alexei